# :hover wont work on hovering link inside paragraph

Tags: html, css, hover

I tried implementing `:hover` specifically on a link that's inside a paragraph.
the p.hop is hidden but when I hover over the link, nothing happens.

```css
.hop {
  display: none;
}
a.hop2:hover + .hop {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>A <a href="https://www.noisli.com" target="_blank" class="hop2">playlist</a> for happy coding.</p>
<p class="hop">Keep your code close but your playlist closer.</p>`
```

Comment: `.hop` is not next to the a link so that is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` sign selector is used to select the elements that are placed immediately after the specified element but not inside the particular elements.

`.hop` is not next to the link so that is not working, You can use `span` next to `a` tag and get the same result.

```css
.hop {
  display: none;
}
a.hop2:hover + .hop {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>A <a href="https://www.noisli.com" target="_blank" class="hop2">playlist</a> for happy coding.
<span class="hop">Keep your code close but your playlist closer.</span></p>
```